# Compact notation for "morphism parameter" of a functor?

Tags: category-theory, notation

Sorry about the slightly horrible language in the title. This question isn't so much about a mathematical problem, but about notation; I'm writing up some notes in TeX, and thought about this in connection with the $Hom(\cdot,\cdot)$ (bi-)functor, and while it is straight forward to write $Hom(x,y)$ for objects $x$ and $y$, I feel there isn't a good compact notation for morphisms. I've been using something kludgy like $Hom([x \xrightarrow{f} y],[w \xrightarrow{h} z])$. Isn't there something better?

Comment: What is wrong with $\mathrm {Hom}(f,h)$? It is also common to shorten things and write, for a category $\mathscr C$, $\mathscr C(x,y)$ instead of $\mathrm {Hom}_{\mathscr C}(x,y)$.

Comment: Why not $\mathrm{Hom}(f, h)$ or $\mathrm{Hom}(f: x \to y, h: w \to z)$ if you need the objects?

Comment: Nothing wrong - although, for $Hom(f,h)$, I will then have to specify domain and codomain separately. It all comes down to context, really; I just started wondering, when I really ought to have been doing something better with my time.